# If $X_1, X_2$ are independent $N(0,1)$, is there a nice formula for the dist. of $\frac{\Phi(X_1)}{\Phi(X_1+X_2)}$, where $\Phi$ is the Normal CDF?

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X_1, X_2$ are independent $N(0,1)$, is there a nice formula for the distribution of $\frac{\Phi(X_1)}{\Phi(X_1+X_2)}$, or the ratio of probit functions in general? Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean instead to ask for a formula for the distribution function of the ratio of $\Phi$ functions?

Comment: Yes, the distribution function, thanks!